# Error Message of RequireFieldValidator prevent me to do other action than filling the form

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have a problem with RequireFieldValidator in my form.
When I fill badly the form my Error message is well displayed so that's cool.
The fact is if i decide to not fill the form(after the requirefieldvalidor has been raised) and to click on the cancel button or to click the linkbutton of my menu I can't. So the requirefieldvalidator prevent me to change page and do what i want.
How can I solve this problem?

Sincerely,

Quentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `CausesValidation="False"` on the `cancel` and `linkbutton` buttons

Answer (score 1):

Add button which you want to redirect to some page and set CauseValidation="fasle"

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CauseValidation="false"
              OnClick="cmdCancel_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set validation group for the validators and for the submitting button. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx